# How can i crawl data from hbase using nutch

Tags: hbase, nutch

My requirement is to crawl data from HBASE using Nutch, and then index it into Solr. how can i proceed on this?

Answer (score 1):

Nutch is designed to crawl websites and so does not know how to crawl hbase.

Since you are trying to index content from hbase into solr, you have at least two options:

If you have an application that saves data into hbase, modify it to index the data into solr, after the data is saved in hbase.

You can also write a Map/Reduce job to send data from hbase into solr.

You should also look into the [lily project](http://www.lilyproject.org/lily/index.html). It integrates hbase and solr.

Also if your search queries are simple, you could design your hbase schema, so that you dont need solr.

Comment: Thanks alot i will try to impliment, so its not possible to crawl data from hbase using nutch right?? one more thing i would like to know whether i can crawl from hdfs file system?? thanks for you reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "crawl" is the right terminology to use when it comes to databases. Crawling is a specific use case, when you want to "crawl" web pages, you don't know what you are starting with. You don't know what the end point is. Hence you start at some point and try to discover what lies out there.

When it comes to a database, a NOSQL database like HBase. You already "know" what is in that database. All you have to do is retrieve the information completely, or retrieve partially what's in it based on specific queries.

I see that probably in your case, you could tweak Lucene to build your indexes from the data queried from HBase and then feed these indexes to Solr to create a full pledged search application.

Hope this might be the direction you are looking for.